# How do I correctly initialize Swiper from iDangero.us and JQuery mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, slider, swiper.js

The swiper isn't working as it should. It shows all the slides in one page. I think it's because of the declaration but I cannot find the correct order. I tried to disable jQuery mobile and the slider works but all the app is messed out. I need both of them... What's the correct order?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/idangerous.swiper-2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Also if I disable the idangerous script the navigation buttons dissappear.

I only modified index.js wich is:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#fade").fadeOut( 1500,"swing");
    }
);

//*********************************************************
// Wait for Cordova to Load
//*********************************************************

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
navigator.splashscreen.hide();

    $("#play").click(function() {
        // $.mobile.changePage("#page2", { transition: "pop"});
        $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('change', "#page2", { 
            transition: 'pop',
            reverse: true
        });
        // $("#photo").hide().delay(1000).fadeOut();
            $("#photo").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1);
    });  

    $("#frame").click(function() {
        // $.mobile.changePage("#page2", { transition: "pop"});
        // $("#photo").show().delay(100).fadeOut();
         $("#photo").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1).delay(1).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 300).delay(2000);
    }); 


     var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
     pagination: '.pagination',
     paginationClickable: true
   });
```

}

Comment: wrap swiper initialization code in `pageshow` event and place it inside page div.

Comment: Please post the content of your javascript files.

Comment: Omar, I placed this code:
<script>
     var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
     pagination: '.pagination',
     paginationClickable: true
   });
</script> in the page div but it's not working... it still shows me all the slides together in one page

Comment: Should I still include <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/idangerous.swiper-2.4.min.js"></script>
if I already have jquerry and jquerry mobile or not?

Comment: @Omar I placed the code in the pageshow and it works but it is ugly because first it shows the swiper all on the screen with all the slides and after a second it changes right. Isn't there another way to make it appear at first right? Thanks

Comment: try `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: @Omar its not working with pagebeforshow! I tried to add in the script an alert and that is showing but the slider doen't initialize on pagebeforshow... Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it may work.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#mainpage", function () {
           swiper code here...
    });            
</script>
```